# Left-justifying Pandas DataFrame is almost perfect, but not quite

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` and I'd like to use `df.to_string` in order to pretty print it in tabular form to the screen.

I'm attempting to left-align the contents of the table. It's *almost* perfect. This is what it looks like:

```
ZZZZ                      AAAAAA BBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDDDDDD EEEEEEEEEEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF GGGGGGGGGG
 very_long_name_of_thing   10     2          3       4          5555.77       1234.54         30
 very_long_name_of_thing2  10     2          3       4          5555.99       8765432         30
```

As you can see, there's something that appears to look like a "single space" before each value in the table. I would like to get rid of it if possible.

I currently use this code:

```
def frame_to_text(df):
    f = {x: '{{:<{}s}}'.format(table[column].str.len().max()).format for x in header}

    return df.to_string(justify='left', index=False, formatters=f)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: No additional libraries please.

Comment: `tabulate` maybe helpful.

Comment: @QuangHoang I can't use additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up prepending a single `' '` before each column name... It fixes the issue visually.

Leaving this unanswered for now in case somebody came across a better solution.